# Cassandra 3 node configuration

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra, use latest Cassandra 3.10. I have 3 nodes to link to participate in Cassandra. Cluster name **Test Cluster** same as three nodes. Same Datacenter **dc1** ,Rack as **rack1** and snitch as **GossipingPropertyFileSnitch** used .It Configures

**Node A:**

-seeds : "A,B,C address"

listen_address & rpc_address are same to A node ip address

**Node B:**

-seeds : "A,B,C address"

listen_address & rpc_address are same to B node ip address

**Node C:**

-seeds : "A,B,C address"

listen_address & rpc_address are same to C node ip address

What i am do possibility here listed

i)  suppose if A node is failure get data from node B and C .

ii) If any one or two node failure get data from another node. How to configure these nodes.

I have use Simple Strategy with replication factor 3 has used.
If node failure get node from another node data retrieve so, seeds address or mistaken? Briefly explain what to do.

Comment: You could use DataStax OpsCenter to configure and install Cassandra for you, or read the DataStax documentation

Comment: Yes i have read but little confused in seed address and replication factor

Comment: Replication factor = how many copies of data you need. In a small cluster, you don't need a factor of 3... Seed address only needs to be a single (external) ip address in a small cluster. All nodes must have the same seeds (at least that's how I configure it)

Comment: Ok. I tried three nodes data replicated. If sample java thread run on single node A replicate B and C node. So all node have data. Seed point to all other node is right? my configuration is right.

Comment: Think of the seeds as the "master" or the "brain". Each config points to the same list of servers. If you can start the services and run `nodetool status`, and see servers,  then it works

Comment: While crate keyspace OperationTimedOut: errors={'10.10.10.106': 'Request timed out while waiting for schema agreement. See Session.execute[_async](timeout) and Cluster.max_schema_agreement_wait.'}, last_host=10.10.10.106
Warning: schema version mismatch detected; check the schema versions of your nodes in system.local and system.peers.  error in node A

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions:

If a Node A goes down, then you want to fetch data from node B and C.
If one or two node goes down, you want  to fetch data from other node.

To achieve the above, the replication factor which you have configured is enough to handle the node failure. The wrong configuration is having all your nodes be seed node.

A seed node is used to bootstrap other nodes, So usually first node is started first in a data center as a seed node. Suppose you have 2 data centers. Then you should have 2 seed nodes, as mentioned in below datastax docs:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/initialize/initSingleDS.html

As per your last comment, you have mentioned "schema version mismatch detected". Which is means all your nodes are not in same cluster. Check the schema using nodetool when all your nodes are running

```
nodetool describecluster
```

This should give nodes schema version. All nodes should be same schema version.
So if any one node does not have same version then restart the node till the schema version is same.

Once you fix this schema error, you will be able to create keyspace.